# Parsing XML with object reference creation

Tags: java, android, xml, simple-framework

I'm parsing xml file and trying to create model from it. I'm using Simple XML library. My xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root cycles_count="2">
  <shifts>
    <shift id="0" name="first"/>
    <shift id="1" name="second"/>
    <shift id="2" name="third"/>
    <shift id="3" name="fourth"/>
  </shifts>
  <cycles>
    <cycle name="A" start_date="1334620800000">
        <cycle_shift id="0" />
        <cycle_shift id="0" />
        <cycle_shift id="1" />
    </cycle>

    <cycle name="B" start_date="1334620800000">
        <cycle_shift id="1" />
        <cycle_shift id="1" />
        <cycle_shift id="2" />
    </cycle>
  </cycles>
</root>
```

Is there any way how to create object reference from `cycle_shift` to `shift` based on the same `id`? I want to achieve something like this (simplified version):

```
@Root
public class Shift {

  @Attribute
  int id;

  @Attribute
  String name;
}

@Root
public class Cycle {

  @ElementList
  List<Shift> shifts; // shifts connected by id's
}
```

Change of xml schema is possible too. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Refer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17171504/simple-xml-framework-having-an-inline-like-behaviour-for-objects-in-elementm?rq=1

Answer (score 0):

1. Cycle through the Shifts and create those objects
2. Create a dictionary with the id of the Shift as the key and the Shift itself as the value
3. Loop through all your Cycles and create those objects
4. When creating the List of Shifts belonging to that Cycle, just reference the id from the Cycle's property and look up the Shift from the dictionary you created earlier and add it to the list.

Would that work?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the name attribute [optional](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#optional) on Shift, and get rid of cycle_shift and use only shift instead

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<root cycles_count="2">
  <shifts>
    <shift id="0" name="first"/>
    <shift id="1" name="second"/>
    <shift id="2" name="third"/>
    <shift id="3" name="fourth"/>
 </shifts>
```

```
<cycle name="B" start_date="1334620800000">
    <cycle_shift id="1" />
    <cycle_shift id="1" />
    <cycle_shift id="2" />
</cycle>
```

And your pseudo code will be like this: (I'm using the [inline](http://simple.sourceforge.net/download/stream/doc/tutorial/tutorial.php#inline) modifier)

```
@Root
public class Cycle {

@ElementList(inline=true)
List<Shift> shifts; // shifts connected by id's
}
```

Comment: I think, it's not answer to my question.